# Join with LIKE statement

Tags: mysql, arrays, join

I have two tables:

```
+--------------+     +------------------+
| files        |     | locked           |
|--------------|     |------------------|
| filename     |     | user   | filename|
+--------------+     +------------------+
| /f1/f2/xy.txt|     |  77    | /f1     |
| /f3/xx/xx.doc|     |  65    | /abc    |
| /x.txt       |     |  77    | /f3/xx  |
+--------------+     +------------------+
(The're a lot more files and locked filenames, but so its easier to understand)
```

The table `files` contains a list of all my files. Table `locked` contains a list with folders of files.
For example in row one is defined that the  `user 77` is not allowed to see `files` which begin with `f1`.

So my wish is a statement like this:

```
SELECT filename FROM files f
LEFT JOIN locked l ON f.filename LIKE CONCAT(l.filename,'%')
WHERE user='77';
```

It's not possible for me to do this with `NOT IN(SELECT...)`, because it is to slow.

Comment: Consider posting up a sqlfiddle of same

Comment: If the condition will always be "begins with", use an equals condition using `LEFT()` instead of `LIKE`. This will allow you to use your indexes and speed up the query.

Comment: But how to combine this with the JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12f23/5/0

```
SELECT f.filename FROM files f
LEFT JOIN locked l ON user=77 AND LOCATE(l.filename, f.filename) = 1
WHERE l.filename IS NULL;
```

Result:

```
FILENAME
/x.txt
```